# Need Improvisation with this Unique Array Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm using following code to detect Unique Numbers within Array.

```
// Array
var sortBp = [ 700, 500, 500, 501, 600];


// Find Unique Numbers
Array.prototype.unique = function(){
    var bpAllArrays = this;
    var uniqueArrays = [];
    for(var i=bpAllArrays.length;i--;){
        var uniqueArray = bpAllArrays[i];  
        if($.inArray( uniqueArray, uniqueArrays )===-1){
            uniqueArrays.unshift(uniqueArray);
        }
    }
    return uniqueArrays;
}

// Append Only Unique Numbers
$.each(sortBp.unique(), function(index, value) {
    $("body").append(value);
});
```

This code works fine. Here is working Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ScPbe/

but I want to add another function to detect :

If Very Next Number is present in Array, Remove Higher number & Only append lower Number.

Example : [ 500, 501 ] In this case, I only want 500 to be consider as unique number & not 501

So Final result should look something like :

```
[ 700, 500, 600]
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: what would be the output for [500, 501, 502, 503, 599, 600]?

Comment: My Arrays are not going to be in [ 700, 500, 501, 502, 503, 600] format. It could only be [ 700, 500, 501, 600, 601 ]

Comment: Can the 601 appear before the 600, or only directly after?

Comment: how bout 500 and 600 in your array the very next number 600 is greater than 500 so array should be like [700,500] right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the double values come one after the other (cannot appear anywhere in the array), this solution will be much simpler:

```
var sortBp = [ 700, 500, 500, 501, 600, 900, 900, 901];

for (var cur, last, i=0; i<sortBp.length; i++) {
    cur = sortBp[i];
    if (cur === last || cur === last + 1)
        continue;
    $('body').append(" "+cur);
    last = cur;
}
```

With [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
var last;
$.each(sortBp, function(i, cur) {
    if (cur === last || cur === last + 1)
        return;
    $('body').append(" "+cur);
    last = cur;
});
```

Elegant solution using es5's [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (might need to be shimmed):

```
var display = [];
sortBp.reduce(function(last, cur) {
    if (cur === last || cur === last+1)
        return last;
    display.push(cur);
    return cur;
}, undefined);
$('body').append(display.join(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have comeup with following code. It checks if current value in array is greater than prev value by 1

Here is fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ScPbe/5/

```
   // Array
    var sortBp = [ 700, 500, 500, 501, 600, 601, 610,612];

    // Find Unique Numbers
    Array.prototype.unique = function(){
        var bpAllArrays = this;
        var uniqueArrays = [];
        for(var i=bpAllArrays.length;i--;){
            var uniqueArray = bpAllArrays[i];  
            if($.inArray( uniqueArray, uniqueArrays )===-1){
                uniqueArrays.unshift(uniqueArray);
            }
        }
        return uniqueArrays;
    }

    // Append Only Unique Numbers
    var arr = sortBp.unique();
    $.each(arr, function(index, value) {
        // Chect if Current Value > Prev by 1
        var prev = arr[index - 1];
        if (value - prev !== 1 ) {
             $('body').append(" "+value);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ouch! Why do you search for the current `value` in the `sortBp` array, you already know its `index`

Comment: @Bergi But How do I find prev using index?

Comment: just replace `$.inArray(value, sortBp)` with `index`

Comment: @Bergi I tried that already but that isn't giving me correct result. look here : http://jsfiddle.net/ScPbe/4/

Comment: Uh, I see - you should not get the `prev` value from the `sortBp`, but from the uniqued array of course! See [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ScPbe/5/)